# SameSite cookie warning in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

Im working on a chrome extension that doesn't set or read any cookies. It uses firebase and google analytics if that makes a difference.
I'm getting this warning in the background script console:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at
>   http://doubleclick.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A
>   future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site
>   requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can
>   review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies
>   and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Anybody knows how to get rid of this warning or what could be the trigger?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: _I'm getting this warning in console._ Which console? Active tab/page's or  background script's?

Comment: Doubleclick belongs to Google, and embedding Google Analytics sometimes sets cookies for the doubleclick domain in my experience.

Comment: @hindmost sorry should 've specified. Background script console

Comment: Then that's most likely caused by 3rd-party stuff you using (like GA).

Comment: Is there a way i could disable the warning if it's coming for a 3rd party library like GA or firebase?

Comment: Why if it obviously has no effect on your extension itself? Just ignore it.

Comment: @hindmost users are complaining unfortunately. I know it's not breaking anything but they check the extensions and see the error flag beside my extension and think it's breaking something.

Comment: I can also confirm it's from google analytics somehow. Removing google analytics removes the problem

Comment: tbh, using google analytics in a _background_ script looks weird at least.

Comment: @hindmost where should you use it then? It's not allowed in content scripts.

Comment: Why does you need it at all? Google analytics is for websites, not extensions.

Comment: Are you arguing against the need to collect user behavior data for extensions? But it's fine for websites and apps?